# Monogame "Sprite" type missing

Tags: c#, class, types, monogame

So I'm currently learning Monogame, and my method of learning is a bit backwards. I've been referencing a lot of code examples for various things and I keep coming across something that I yet to find any answer to. The "Sprite" type.

For example:

```
public class MousePosition
{

    public static Vector2 GetMousePos()
    {
        MouseState state = Mouse.GetState();
        Vector2 position = new Vector2(state.X, state.Y);
        return position;
    }

    public bool IsPointOverSprite(float x, float y, Sprite sprite)
    {
        Vector2 pos = GetMousePos();
        return (sprite.getTexture().getBounds().Contains(pos));
    }

}
```

This is a snippet someone else wrote to determine if the cursor is over a particular sprite. It uses the Sprite type and as far as VS2017 is concerned that type does not exist.

Is this a class that I have to write myself? If so, what does that entail?

Is this a class whose name has simply been changed, and I can't find the replacement? If so, please tell me what it is.

Is there a workaround that a newbie like me is blind to?

Comment: Your code snippet is from a Java source, not C#, and is poorly written. I would be glad to share an equivalent code in C#  MonoGame, if you would like?

Answer (score 0):

The Sprite class is part of MonoGame Extended.  The installation instructions can be found [here](http://docs.monogameextended.net/Installation/).

I would suggest looking at tutorials for XNA.  The XNA code will run directly in MonoGame.

Comment: MonoGame.Extended does have a `Sprite` class but I don't think it's the same one shown in the OP's code. For starters, Extended follows standard [C# naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) so a `getTexture()` method would never be a thing.

Comment: @craftworkgames, Thank you for pointing that out. The OP's example is from a Java source.  The five method calls, to get the mouse over a sprite, that has been bothering me.